# Optimization of an integrated function in R

Tags: r, optimization, integration

I would like to find the optimum value of `a` for the following integration which is a function of `x`

```
  integrand <- function(x,a) {
          D=a/((x+1)*sqrt(x+a))
          D
        }
```

I can do the integration for fixed value of `a`. For example, if a=5

```
> integrate(integrand,0,5,a=5)$value
[1] 3.490687
```

But I want to find the optimum value using the `optim()` function in R or any available built-in optimization function. I have tried the following code, unfortunately it is not working,

```
optim(5,integrate(integrand, lower = 0, upper = 5))
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If the integral is the area below some function, why you want to optimize a number?

Answer (score -1):

You can use the 'optimize' function, which is ideal for one-parameter optimization:

```
optimize(f = integrand, interval = c(0, 5), a = 5)
```

Comment: How do I know the value of `a` is `5`? I used it as an example. My aim is to find the optimum value of `a`